# WPF TextSearch.TextPath - possible to use with string?

Tags: wpf, combobox

We have an *ObservableCollection*<*string>* as the ItemsSource for a ComboBox.
In trying to use the auto-complete functionality in a 3rd party ComboBox, TextSearch.TextPath is used.
How would one specify the 'path' to the value in a *string* object, if it is possible at all?
Thanks --

Comment: Just set TextSearch.TextPath = "".

Comment: @DipenShah Thanks, that seems to work as desired.

Comment: @Nuber8 Gladto help, just mark it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Set TextSearch.TextPath = "" to use *string* object for searching.